# How to add animation for showing and hiding actionbar in android?

Tags: android

'public class GrammarFragment extends Fragment {

```
public GrammarFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_grammar, container, false);
    ObservableWebView webView = (ObservableWebView) v.findViewById(R.id.grammar_webview);
    //webView.loadData("ABC", "text/html", "UTF-8");
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/grammar/danhtu.html");
    webView.setScrollViewCallbacks(new ObservableScrollViewCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged(int scrollY, boolean firstScroll, boolean dragging) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onDownMotionEvent() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpOrCancelMotionEvent(ScrollState scrollState) {
            ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
            if (scrollState == ScrollState.UP) {
                if (actionBar != null) actionBar.hide();
            } else if (scrollState == ScrollState.DOWN) {
                if (actionBar != null) actionBar.show();
            }
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

}
`When action bar is being hide or showed, it disappears or appears on the screen almost instantly without smooth animation sliding down or up. Is there any way I can configure it to show or hide smoothly?

Comment: paste your code

Comment: What kind of layout are you using? Are you using `CoordinatorLayout` or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code like this

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            if (scrollState == ScrollState.UP) {
                if (toolbar != null) {
                    toolbar.animate().translationY(-toolbar.getBottom()).
                            setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
                }
            } else if (scrollState == ScrollState.DOWN) {
                if (toolbar != null)
                    toolbar.animate().translationY(0).
                            setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).start();
            }
```

Comment: I put after this line "ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();"

Comment: By default , animation is enabled in actionbar hide and show. You want to put different animation?

Comment: you can try this code to disable animation. And see if that animation  is working

ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                                                actionBar.setShowHideAnimationEnabled(false);
                                                if (actionBar != null && actionBar.isShowing())
                                                    actionBar.hide();
                                                else
                                                    actionBar.show();

Comment: I just tried , its working. You dont need to put setShowHideAnimation(true). It true by defualt

Comment: i dont understand . Did you use actionBar.setShowHideAnimationEnabled(false); to remove the animation. And see how it looks? Do you see any changes with this code and without this code?

Comment: They are the same in 2 cases

Comment: That code must work. You might do something wrong somewhere else in the code. I just checked with that code and It working perfectly. You can share your all code so that I can help you

Comment: The other easy way is to use Toolbar :)

Comment: Can you give me your your email?

Comment: ajay.shrestha005@gmail.com

Comment: Actually, I use toolbar as Actionbar